# why I cannot cd into /var/lib/mysql

Tags: linux, file-permissions

The structure is the following

```
ravas@ravas-desk-lmde /var/lib $ pwd
/var/lib
ravas@ravas-desk-lmde /var/lib $ ls -l | grep mysql
drwx------ 13 mysql   mysql   4096 Feb 10 22:32 mysql
```

When I try to get into  /var/lib/mysql, I don't have rights

```
ravas@ravas-desk-lmde /var/lib $ cd mysql/
bash: cd: mysql/: Permission denied
```

though I belong to the mysql group

```
ravas@ravas-desk-lmde /var/lib $ groups ravas 
ravas : ravas adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev lpadmin sambashare mysql
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 62):

```
sudo -i
```

then

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: `sudo -i` solved this issue for me, on ubuntu with a directory i ran the following on `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql ...`

Comment: how is this relevant to permissions?

Answer (score 4):

mysql user is the only one that can access to the directory, you can use root to access there and change permissions, or you can change the directory permissions to 740 with

`chmod 740 /var/lib/mysql`

permissions are divided in 3 parts user/group/else. and you have

```
drwx------
```

d= directory

r= read = 4

w=write = 2

x=execute = 1

so the "owner" has read(4) + write(2) + execute(1) = 7 permissions in that directory

every one else doesn't

Comment: You should use 750 or 755 if you want others to access the directory. 740 is sufficient for members of the right group to read the immediate directory listing and nothing more. The execute bit is more important here.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql` group has no access to that directory. The rights for the `mysql` user are `rwx`, but group and others get `---`, so being in the `mysql` group doesn't give you what you want.

Comment: I see, so to cd into it I need either to add the mysql group, or sudo -i and to then cd mysql. Do you think it's a bad idea the former solution regarding security?

Comment: It may be a bad idea from the point of view of packaging - when you upgrade mysql it could reinstall the old privileges on /var/lib/mysql.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` group doesn't have permissions on the directory, only the `mysql` user.

Answer (score 1):

From given inputs it is clear that **only** owner `mysql` has `read, write, execute` permission on `/var/lib/mysql` directory.

And current login user - `ravas`  is part of mysql group. Hence `ravas` user can `cd` to `/var/lib/mysql` directory if group `mysql` has `x (ie execute)` permission on `/var/lib/mysql`.

Hence `chmod g+rx /var/lib/mysql` OR `chmod 750 /var/lib/mysql` would allow `ravas` user to `cd` to `/var/lib/mysql` and read directory contents (ie. list files)

- **Note:** `x/Execute` permission for directories allows `cd` to directory

Answer (score 1):

Each file and directory has three user based permission groups:

**owner** - The Owner permissions apply only the owner of the file or directory, they will not impact the actions of other users.

**group** - The Group permissions apply only to the group that has been assigned to the file or directory, they will not effect the actions of other users.

**all users** - The All Users permissions apply to all other users on the system, this is the permission group that you want to watch the most.

> drwx------ 13 mysql   mysql   4096 Feb 10 22:32 mysql

the above show mysql folder Permissions is 700, So mysql user have all read,write and execute permission. mysql group have none permission. although, ravas user belong mysql group. haven't permission.

Comment: Please edit this answer for better clarity. I currently can't follow it.